# Nativescript NavigationButton adding more events

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I have little problem with go back button in ActionBar. I need to add into native go back function code for stop video playing.

Is it somehow possible to inject this native function?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to listen to a page destroy or leave event as there may be multiple ways to leave a page (Android hardware backbutton for instance). The exact code depends on whether or not you're using {N} with Angular.